# Backbone.js Event Binding not firing

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-events

The `select` is rendered from a template and does not exist in the DOM until `renderGroups()` is called.

I thought the *events were bound to the view* so it wouldn't necessarily matter if the select didn't exist in the DOM at first?

I'm new to `backbone.js` so its probably pretty obvious:

```
var DirectoryView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $("table tbody"),
    initialize: function(){
        // Populate our collection
        this.collection = new Directory(contacts);

        // Get our unique groups
        var groups = this.getGroups();
        this.renderGroups(groups);
    },

    renderGroups: function(groups) {
        var group = $("#groups");

        var groupView = new GroupView({
            model: {groups: groups}
        })

        group.append(groupView.render().el)

    },

    events : {
        "change select" : "select"
    },

    select: function(e) {
        console.log("hello")
    },

    getGroups: function() {
        // Pluck all the group properties from our array of contacts and return the unique groups
        return _.uniq(this.collection.pluck("group"), false, function(group){
            return group.toLowerCase();
        });
    }
});
```

**template**:

```
    <script id="group-option-tmpl" type="text/template">
        <option value="all">All</option>
        <% _.each(groups, function(group) { %>
            <option value="<%= group %>"><%= group %></option>
        <% }); %>
    </script>
```

**JSFiddle**

http://jsfiddle.net/BDgMu/1/

Comment: What happens if you rename `renderGroups` to `render`?

Comment: @jsalonen I can check, but the render() function actually renders some contacts.  the DirectoryView is a "master" view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like `$("#groups")` is not located inside `DirectoryView.el`. I suppose `$('#groups')` is `select`.

Comment: $("#groups") is a wrapping div the select is inserted into

Comment: Is that wrapper located inside `$("table tbody")` ? Where is your `select` tag?

Comment: I see, because its a "master view" made of other views, I set el to "body" and it works ok

Comment: I wouldn't use whole `body` as `view.el`. I think `.container` is better.